# JavaScript Empty Field and Unanswered radio, Validation on Button Press W/ Alert

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a JavaScript validation code that would provide an Alert when the field is left empty and a check mark is not provided (male or female option), on button press.

Here is my HTML CODE:

```html
    <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">APPLICATION</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Background Information</h3>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age">

    <h4>Gender</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender-male"/>
            <label for="gender-male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender-female"/>
            <label for="gender-female">Female</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="terms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: which field should not be empty ? one ? all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event listener to the button and check values of inputs as below. 
`return false` in the case of error.

```js
document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click',
    function(){
        //text inputs
        if(!document.getElementById('fullname').value){
            alert('full name is required');
            return false;
        }
        //radio buttons
        var genderSet = false;
        var genderBtns = document.getElementsByName('gender');
        //console.log(genderBtns);
        for(var i=0, btn; btn=genderBtns[i];++i){
            if(btn.checked){
                genderSet=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!genderSet){
            alert('Gender is required');
            return false
        }
        console.log('success');
        alert('success');
        return true;

    }
);
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">APPLICATION</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Background Information</h3>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age">

    <h4>Gender</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender-male"/>
            <label for="gender-male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender-female"/>
            <label for="gender-female">Female</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="terms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" id="btnNext" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

If all inputs are inside a `form` then it is better to listen `submit` event and refer to inputs by their names.

```
<form id="Form1">
    <!-- your HTML -->
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('Form1').addEventListener('submit',
        function(){
            if(!this['firstname'].value) //**this** here is the form here. 'firstname' is **name** attribute, not **id**
                return false;
            if(!this['gender'].value)
                return false;
        });
</script>
```